# Como restringir que sejam exibidas algumas pastas na galeria? android

Tags: java, android

Eu sei listar todas as fotos da galeria mas eu preciso que não apareça a pasta Download na listagem. Sei que posso filtrar mas não consigo fazer funcionar.

Eu não que parametro na query devo colacar para que não seja exibida a pasta download. Mas se alguém souber como exibir na galeria apenas as fotos da pasta câmera já está de bom grado.

Meu código que lista todos funciona mas como faz para filtrar algumas pastas?

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(data.getData(),
                        new String[] { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA },
                        null, null, null);
                if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
                    try{
                        int indice = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                        caminho = cursor.getString(indice);
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Segui isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713850/android-how-to-hide-folder-from-appearing-in-the-gallery e deu certo.

criei um arquivo.nomedia e coloquei na minha pasta que não queria que fosse exibida.